# How to display values in a dictionary?

Tags: c#

How would you list out values in a dictionary where the key is a string and the values are a string array?

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> items = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
string[] products1 = { "item12", "item13", "item14", "item15"};
string[] products2 = {"item1","item2","item3","item4"};
string[] products3 = { "item12", "item22", "item23", "item42", "item52"};
items.Add("products1", products1);
items.Add("products2", products2);
items.Add("products3", products3);
```

I would like to print out the following:

```
products1: item12, item13, item14, item15
products2: item1, item2, item3, item4
products3: item12, item22, item23, item42, item52
```

Comment: What do you mean by "list out values"?

Comment: That looks extremely wrong and defeats the purpose of having a Dictionary list. If you have a product with different options then properly store the options selected from a given product instead

Comment: It's entirely possible he's just giving dummy data that appears to make little sense in this context. I think the question appears pretty straight forward - print out all key and values, where values are arrays themselves. @slothLi you could help by giving an example of the output you want. and clarifying your question a bit

Comment: how would I list out the strings in like lets say products1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list out just the items associated with the key:

```
String.Join(", ", items[key]);
```

To list out all products and all items:

```
foreach (var key in items.Keys)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, String.Join(", ", items[key]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry it was dummy data. Prix

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a collection of collections (a dictionary of lists,) you'll need a nested loop. This way, you'll be able to process each item individually.

```
foreach (string productKey in items.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Product: ", productKey);
    foreach (string item in items[productKey])
    {
        Console.Write("\t", item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You can choose to ammend this to print out all the products on one line, as well.